# C# Parallel ForEach Unhandled User Code For WorkItem Fields Information Retriving

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

Currently I am working on a project to get information from the TFS
trying to build a custom tool

I have decided to improve the performance of the tool and i got stuck with 1 issue using the Parallel option (.Net 4+)

Remark: I have tried placing safe thread on the queryresults and item it didn't help code samples are at the bottom

I am trying to perform the next code:

```
    WorkItemCollection queryResults;
//Query run to populate the collection
                    Parallel.ForEach<WorkItem>(queryResults.Cast<WorkItem>(), item => {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Fields.GetById(AttributeCode.Default.RemainingWork).Value);
        });
```

Error quote:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll but was not handled in user code

Log from Exception Catch:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.KeyCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.PagingFieldReader.ProcessFields(Int32 row, IEnumerable`1 fieldIds, Dictionary`2 fields)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.PagingFieldReader.ProcessRevision(Int32 row, Dictionary`2 rowMap, Dictionary`2 plainFields, Dictionary`2 textFields)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.PagingFieldReader.Read(Int32 row, Int32[] fields)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemCollection.QueryFieldValues(Int32 index, Int32[] fields)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.get_IsAccessDenied()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.QueryFieldValue(Int32 field)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemFieldData.GetFieldValue(Int32 id, Int32 revision)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.CheckUpdateCachedData()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.get_Type()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.get_Fields()

Block protection on the items not sure if i've done it right:

```
WorkItemCollection queryResults;
    //Query run to populate the collection
        BlockingCollection<WorkItem> bc = new BlockingCollection<WorkItem>();
        WorkItem temp;
        Parallel.ForEach<WorkItem>(queryResults.Cast<WorkItem>(), item =>
        {
            bc.Add(item);
            if (bc.TryTake(out temp))
                Console.WriteLine(temp.Fields[CoreField.CreatedBy]);
        });
```

Error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.KeyCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.PagingFieldReader.ProcessFields(Int32 row, IEnumerable`1 fieldIds, Dictionary`2 fields)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.PagingFieldReader.ProcessRevision(Int32 row, Dictionary`2 rowMap, Dictionary`2 plainFields, Dictionary`2 textFields)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.PagingFieldReader.Read(Int32 row, Int32[] fields)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemCollection.QueryFieldValues(Int32 index, Int32[] fields)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.get_IsAccessDenied()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.QueryFieldValue(Int32 field)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in SW-QA Tasks.exe
>   WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemFieldData.GetFieldValue(Int32 id, Int32 revision)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.CheckUpdateCachedData()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.get_Type()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.get_Fields()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.KeyCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.PagingFieldReader.ProcessFields(Int32 row, IEnumerable`1 fieldIds, Dictionary`2 fields)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.PagingFieldReader.ProcessRevision(Int32 row, D

Comment: Is `queryResults` a thread-safe collection?

Comment: No it's no a thread-safe collection

Comment: There must be something missing here.  As the error says, the collection is being modified.  Where is the code that is modifying the collection?  (FWIW, the `Parallel.ForEach` probably has nothing to do with this problem--this is a common problem that occurs whenever you modify a collection while looping through the contents of that collection).

Comment: James I would agree but after testing the code with just printing item every thing works good if i try to print item.Fields[CoreField.CreatedDate] it fails

Comment: You should try using a thread safe collection like `BlockingCollection<T>` - I believe the Cast is actually modifying `queryResults` and causing your problem.

Comment: @viperguynaz i wasn't able to add a BlockingCollection to the queryResults I have tried the next and it helped a little bit but after 100 instances it failed: 
bc.Add(item); -- if (bc.TryTake(out item)) -- console print

Comment: you need to copy queryResults into a BlockingCollection or instantiate queryResults as a BlockingColection.

Comment: @viperguynaz I have done the copying tried it for the WorkItemCollection and WorkItem didn't help only solution was lock(sync) and it works slower then the 1 threaded foreach for now ill use it until I will find a solution